# Relation between following inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality

given the following three distances $r_i, r_j, r_u$ and following relationship

$$0< \frac{r_u}{r_i} < 1$$
$$0< \frac{r_u}{r_j} < 1$$

What is the relation between $$\frac{r_i}{r_j} = ?$$

To further elaborate, I need the minimum of $\frac{r_u}{r_i}$ and $\frac{r_u}{r_i}$, so it means I should need the maximum of $\frac{r_i}{r_j}$. This I have found through multiple iterations in Matlab. But I need mathematical proof.

The image below shows the depiction of how my scenario looks like!

[image]

Comment: Unless there are any other constraints, we cannot say anything about $r_i/r_j$.

Comment: In case all the r's are positive (which I think they are since you call them distances) all you have is that $r_u < r_i$ and $r_u < r_j$.  The ratio $r_i/r_j$ could be either miniscule or enormous.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this......

$r_u + x = r_i$  where $0<x<\infty$ ........which satisfies $0<\frac{r_u}{r_i}<1$

Similarly $r_u + y = r_j$  where $0<y<\infty$ ......which satisfies $0<\frac{r_u}{r_j}<1$

Therefore $0<\frac{r_u+x}{r_u+y}<\infty$ ranging from $x\to0$ and $y\to\infty$ to

$x\to\infty$ and $y\to0$ where $r_u$ is a finite number

Hence $0<\frac{r_i}{r_j}<\infty$